# Remove square brackets from a text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, text, brackets

I have this ajax function returns data as in  plain text form.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/addObstacles",
            cache: false,   
            datatype: "text/plain",
            success: function (data) {
                var obstacles = data.split('\n');
                for(var i = 0;i < obstacles.length;i++){
                    if(!obstacles[i] == ''){
                        console.log(obstacles[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

> console.log(obstacles[i]):
>
> ```
> [[90, 90], [90, 112], [100, 112], [100, 100], [200, 100], [200, 125], [240, 125], [240, 121]]
> ```

**I want to get rid of all square brackets and the commas after every element and it should look like this:**

```
90,90 90,112 100,112 100,100 200,100 200,125 240,125 240,121
```

As this data will be the points for drawing a SVG polyline dynamically.
I tried many regex and strip() but no luck.

Comment: `obstacles[i].replace(/(\[.*?\])/g, '');` ,`obstacles[i].replace(/ *\[[^\]]*]/g, '');` I tried these.

Comment: Use brute force: `.replace(/\[|\],|\]/g, '')`.

Comment: Great.. Works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method

```js
const arr = [[90, 90], [90, 112], [100, 112], [100, 100], [200, 100], [200, 125], [240, 125], [240, 121]];

const res = arr.flat();


//for your desire result
let start = res.shift();
let end   = res.pop();
let center= res.reduce((acc,b,i)=>{
   let l = i+1;
   if(l%2 == 0){
    acc.push(`${res[i-1]} ${b}`)
   }
   return acc
},[])


console.log(start+','+center.join(',')+','+end)
```

Comment: This throws an error `arr.flat is not a function` .
obstacles[i] is not an array it's just a text returned by python after reading a text file.

Comment: @Shyam3089 .is that text file but all in above same format  `[[n,n]...]` like this. Better try with `JSON.parse(obstacles[i]).falt()`. if still not working please post `obstacles`

Comment: @Prasanth  Thanks. Now above code give this: `Array(16) [ 90, 90, 90, 112, 100, 112, 100, 100, 200, 100, … ]`
May be I can remove commas after every 2 elements to get desired structure.